# Who started to call Hermione "Hermy"?

Tags: harry-potter

I remember that Hermione was nicknamed Hermy by someone in the HP series. I am not sure of the answer, so I have asked it out.

Comment: Your question and your question title are asking two different questions. The answer to your question title is Grawp, but the answer to your question body is Hagrid.

Comment: Yeah, Harry, now I win by technical default! *evil laugh*

Comment: @TylerH I see a question mark only in my title.

Comment: @MacCooper You already were the true winner when you solved the CAPTCHA :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Hagrid did, in order to make it easier for his big little brother to remember her rather more difficult full name:

> “An’ this is Hermione, see? Her—” Hagrid hesitated. Turning to Hermione, he said, “Would yeh mind if he called yeh Hermy, Hermione? On’y it’s a difficult name fer him ter remember.”
>
> *Order of the Phoenix, Ch. 30 - Grawp*

Comment: Haha, how many seconds was in that? :D

Comment: @MacCooper If I am not mistaken, it was 5 seconds.

Comment: Dunno, not that much apart for sure :D

Answer (score 22):

It was Grawp, Hagrid's half-brother. He couldn't pronounce Hermione: Hermy was the best he could do, best seen when Umbridge, Harry and Hermione are in the Forbidden Forest togther:

> '"HERMY!" roared Grawp. "WHERE HAGGER?"'
>   -  *The Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 33, *Fight and Flight*, p. 758

He couldn't manage Hagrid, either (he went with Hagger).

EDIT:
Krum also had trouble with her name, and pronounced it "Herm-own-ninny", though Grawp is most likely who you're thinking of (Krum only said it wrong once, and it wasn't a nickname).

Comment: Technically Grawpy called her by this name while Hagrid nicknamed Hermione.

Comment: @HarryJames haha yeah you're right :D I guess BMWurm wins by defult :D

Comment: Yeah, Victor was almost as clever as Grawp :P from the Yule Ball: *Hermione was now teaching Krum to say her name properly; he kept calling her “Hermy-own.”
“Her-my-oh-nee,” she said slowly and clearly.
“Herm-own-ninny.”
“Close enough,” she said, catching Harry’s eye and grinning.*

Comment: @BMWurm, I dont bloody believe this :D how many seconds between you commenting and my edit confirming?

Comment: @MacCooper Not sure, I have the box with the books on my shelf ... needed time to type :P

Comment: @BMWurm haha I just Googled it. I felt all proud for finding it, until I refreshed the page :P I got it wrong anyway, I added a Y in haha

Comment: @BMWurm I dont beleive this chain of coincidence. Both of you please confirm whether you are bots or humans. :) Which is the most common number in the HP series?

Comment: @HarryJames, seven *sniff*

Comment: I knew @BMWurm was a bot!! -_-

Comment: @HarryJames, its been two minutes. He let the side down :(

Comment: Bots are bad. They don't cry when Dumbledore falls off the Tower. So I am accepting your answer :)

Comment: @HarryJames [SEVEN](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106582/harry-potter-why-7)!

Comment: @Rand al'thor, please by all means get the community mass upvoting my answer xD

Comment: @MacCooper I just advertised it to everyone in the Mos Eisley chatroom; you should get some upvotes coming in :-D

Comment: No pity votes from me.

Comment: Needs a citation for the quote.  At least a page number and book title, preferably a volume number as well.

Comment: @Wad Cheber, pfft, be my guest ;) haha buy you're right. I'll stick it in tomorrow (I mean, later today). I actually know fairly precisely where this is in the book

Comment: Chapter 33, *Fight and Flight*, p. 758, *Order of the Phoenix*, Volume 5, according to this site:  http://webpages.charter.net/jtjem/Holy%20Trinity%203/hpootp.htm

Comment: That suggests that the previous answer is a bit better than this one, because Hagrid asked Hermione if Grawp could call her "Hermy" three chapters before Grawp did so in your quote.

Comment: @BMWurm But that was a language thing - that's not fair to say it was an intelligence thing. It's not a usual name after all. Also that scene was there to help the readers.

Comment: @HarryJames So I'm bad because I didn't cry? I see... Interesting.. Well I don't think so and neither do other people in my life. Maybe they're bots too. Intriguing. Be careful or we might take over! But no. It's not that simple in reality. At least I don't think I cried. I seldom did cry in the books or any other time for that matter but I am certain I'm not alone there.