# What actually is Arithmancy?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, arithmancy

A subject taken by some students at Hogwarts is **Arithmancy**.

Throughout the Harry Potter series, we don't seem to be given much information as to what arithmancy actually is.

For example, Defence Against the Dark Arts involves spells and techniques to battle dark creatures/wizards, History of Magic is... supposed to be history of magic (but under Professor Binn's tutorship is mostly just goblin rebellions), Muggle Studies is the study of Muggles, Transfiguration is turning one object into another, Divination is trying to see into the future and Astronomy is studying the sky, stars and constellations and what they mean.

**What actually is arithmancy**?

Is it just Muggle mathematics, or is it a complicated business used in spell creation (a theme often seen in fanfiction), or...?

Comment: Arithmancy (in the real world, not in the Harry Potter books) is not really mathematics—it's more like number-based divination. I don't see much of a reason to believe it's something else in the Potterverse.

Comment: Arithmancy is a Freudian slip by JKR and the main reason she wrote the books: you put a maths problem in, _magic_ happens, and you get the solution out.

Comment: Just for comparison, the _Laundry_ series by Stross, has as one of its key concepts, the idea that certain obscure forms of mathematics can act as  spells. Not unreasonable if one accepts that spellcasting is performed by manipulating symbols according to certain rules. (Author's warning: These stories will be getting progressively darker as the Great Old Ones gain strength.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So is it numerology? You know, 7 is lucky, 8 is unlucky, like that?

Comment: The art of the mathemagician

Comment: We need a similar question regarding Ancient Runes. If they are only about translations, why does Hogwarts offer 5 years of instruction -- when a latin class would be much more useful?

Comment: @DavidBanner Spells only work when they're in *mangled* Latin. Teaching students proper Latin is counterintuitive.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/hogwarts/classes/arithmancy.html) in the [reasonably reliable](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=3126222#3126222) HP Lexicon (emphasis mine):

> Arithmancy is **a branch of magic that is concerned with the magical properties of numbers**; someone who practices Arithmancy is called an Arithmancer. For example, in the 1200s, Bridget Wenlock, a famous Arithmancer, discovered the magical properties of the number seven. An O.W.L. in Arithmancy is required to apply for a curse-breaker's job at Gringott's.
>
> Arithmancy at Hogwarts is taught by Professor Vector. In her class, **students are expected to write essays and to be able to understand complicated number charts**, which are part of their homework. Hermione Granger appears to be the only Gryffindor in her year who attempted an O.W.L. in this subject (which is her favourite).

Comment: “Professor Vector”. Nice math pun.

Comment: The number 7 had been associated with magical properties far earlier than the 1200s. Seems like a silly claim to make on the Lexicon's part.

Comment: @KRyan Sure, but in the Potterverse this is canonical - see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106582/harry-potter-why-7/106584#106584).

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, it really wasn't a criticism of the answer, just commentary that the canon is silly.

Comment: @KRyan A young bespectacled orphan saves the world by shouting faux Latin very loudly, and [you're complaining that a scientific/mathematical proof came after a bunch of folklore going "This seems to work"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallpox_vaccine)? Interesting calibration on your suspension of disbelief.

Comment: "Hermione Grange appears to be the only Gryffindor in her year who attempted an O.W.L. in this subject" - Even the wizarding world hates math and accounting.

Comment: Presumably studied by [a mathemagician](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/beHN2wZ8dYk/hqdefault.jpg)

Answer (score 40):

From **JK Rowling** Herself.

> Stephen Fry:What is Arithmancy?
>
> JK Rowling: Well your guess is as good as mine Stephen. Arithmancy is
>   predicting the future using numbers. I’ve decided there’s a bit of
>   numerology in there as well but how you do it I really don’t know.

This is about all we know other then that Hermione talks about it and they talk about the numbers and figures she deals with being complex.

Comment: If Stephen Fry doesn't know then it really is a mystery.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 If neither Stephen Fry not JKR knows, _then_ it really is a mystery!

Comment: Predicting the future using numbers? Sounds like an actuary to me...

Comment: @crunch A late relative of mine was an actuary and joked that an actuary can walk into a room and tell you how many people will die, a Sicilian actuary can walk into the room and tell you which ones.

Comment: predicting the future sounds like divination to me, and Hermione disliked that, so why would she like Arithmancy if this is what it really is?

Comment: @Michael the use of statistics type math, to figure out the future or possibilities would appeal much more to hermione, then looking at tea leaves and guessing what they looked like.

Answer (score 23):

Not original with Rowling, it's a real word, albeit rare. The [online OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/10772?redirectedFrom=arithmancy) defines "arithmancy" as "divination by numbers" (also called "arithmomancy") and gives two quotations:

> 1577   W. Harrison *Hist. Descr. Islande Brit.* i. ix. f. 28/2, in R. Holinshed *Chron.* I   An old kind of arithmancie, fathered on Pythagoras, yet never invented by him.
>
> 1878   J. H. Gray *China* II. xvii. 25   Other systems of telling fortunes are in vogue, as for instance..arithmancy.

The following quotation from ["Turjan of Miir"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?94067) by [Jack Vance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Vance), about mathematics and magic, is probably not what JKR had in mind:

> In this fashion did Turjan enter his apprenticeship to Pandelume. Day and far into the opalescent Embelyon night he worked under Pandelume's unseen tutelage. He learned the secret of renewed youth, many spells of the ancients, and a strange abstract lore that Pandelume termed "Mathematics."
>
> "Within this instrument," said Pandelume, "resides the Universe. Passive in itself and not of sorcery, it elucidates every problem, each phase of existence, all the secrets of time and space. Your spells and runes are built upon its power and codified according to a great underlying mosaic of magic. The design of this mosaic we cannot surmise; our knowledge is didactic, empirical, arbitrary. Phandaal glimpsed the pattern and so was able to formulate many of the spells which bear his name. I have endeavored through the ages to break the clouded glass, but so far my research has failed. He who discovers the pattern will know all of sorcery and be a man powerful beyond comprehension."
>
> So Turjan applied himself to the study and learned many of the simpler routines.
>
> "I find herein a wonderful beauty," he told Pandelume. "This is no science, this is art, where equations fall away to elements like resolving chords, and where always prevails a symmetry either explicit or multiplex, but always of a crystalline serenity."

Answer (score 10):

Arithmancy is close to a synonym of **data science** in the muggle world. It is about inferencing and prediction from numbers.

The fact that it has *numerology* in it, is the only thing that makes it different from present-day data science (or more precisely **predictive analytics**).

So, Arithmancy = (Present day predictive analytics + Numerology)

The proof for the above is an [interview of Stephen Fry with JKR](http://www.harrypotterspage.com/STEPHEN%20FRY%20INTERVIEW%20WITH%20Jkr.htm):

> Stephen Fry: Can you explain in words of less than two syllables what
>   Arithmancy is?
>
> JK Rowling: Well your guess is as good as mine Stephen… Well, really it's predicting the future using numbers, but I've also decided there's a bit of numerology in there as well.

Comment: It's like data science but magical ... so **data magic** then? ;-)